# Type Juggling with Existentials at Runtime

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, gadt, existential-type, combinators

I'm playing around with existentials and GADTs in Haskell, and I'm trying to define a DSL for combinators (such as SKI). I have the GADT working, as well as a reduction function which works fine (and isn't really relevant to the question)

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, ExistentialQuantification #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Data.Monoid
import Control.Monad

data Comb t where
    S :: Comb ((a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c)
    K :: Comb (a -> b -> a)
    I :: Comb (a -> a)
    B :: Comb ((b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c)
    C :: Comb ((b -> a -> c) -> a -> b -> c)
    W :: Comb ((a -> a -> b) -> a -> b)
    (:$) :: Comb (a -> b) -> Comb a -> Comb b
```

What I'm trying to do now is define a way to read combinator strings in from the user at runtime. Obviously, I need an existential type to do this, since the GADT's type information needs to be hidden.

```
data CombBox = forall a. CombBox { unCombBox :: Comb a }

($$) :: CombBox -> CombBox -> Maybe CombBox
x $$ y = undefined -- ???
```

I would like the `($$)` function to somehow "look inside" the `CombBox` existentials at runtime and, if it is possible to combine the two combinators using `:$` and get a well-typed result, I would like the result to be that. Otherwise, I want `Nothing`. So, for example,

```
CombBox S $$ CombBox K ==> Just (CombBox (S :$ K))
CombBox W $$ CombBox I ==> Nothing
```

The latter should fail because `W` expects a 2-ary function where `I` takes one argument. But I would like to relegate this check to the runtime, and I'm not sure if such a thing is possible in the Haskell (+ GHC extensions) type system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get ready to learn about *dependent pairs* and *singletons*!

---

I'm going to rewrite your system a little bit to simplify it.

First off, I'm going to shrink your universe of types from *all of Haskell* to a much simpler universe consisting of a single primitive type and arrows.

```
infixr 0 :->
data Type = Unit | Type :-> Type
```

Hopefully you should be able to see how to extend this with more primitive types.

I'm also going to remove most of the bits from `Comb`, since they can all be expressed in terms of one another.

```
data Comb a where
    S :: Comb ((a :-> b :-> c) :-> (a :-> b) :-> a :-> c)
    K :: Comb (a :-> b :-> a)
    (:$) :: Comb (a :-> b) -> Comb a -> Comb b

i = S :$ K :$ i
b = (S :$ (K :$ S)) :$ K
c = S :$ (S :$ (K :$ (S :$ (K :$ S) :$ K)) :$ S) :$ (K :$ K)
w = S :$ S :$ (S :$ K)
```

---

Now to your question. As you correctly surmised, when you're reading user input you can't predict statically what the type of the resulting term will be, so you need to existentially quantify it.

```
data Ex f = forall a. Ex (f a)
```

The problem is: how do you recover the type information in order to be able to manipulate terms? We can pair up a `Comb` with another value which you can pattern-match on at runtime to *learn* the type of the `Comb`. Here's a combinator for pairing things up.

```
data (f :*: g) i = f i :*: g i
```

(I lifted both of these types from [the *Hasochism* paper](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/hasochism.pdf).) `:*:` pairs up two types ensuring that their indices are equal. We'll use it together with `Ex` to simulate a *dependent pair* or *sigma* type: a pair of values for whom the type of the second component depends on the value of the first. The idea is that `f` will be a GADT which tells you something about its index, so pattern matching on `f` gives you information about the type of `g`.

```
type Sg f g = Ex (f :*: g)
pattern Sg x y = Ex (x :*: y)
```

Now the clever part: coming up with a GADT which tells you about a combinator term's type.

```
data Typey t where
    Unity :: Typey Unit
    Arry :: Typey a -> Typey b -> Typey (a :-> b)
```

`Typey` is called a *singleton*. For a given `t`, there exists exactly one value of type `Typey t`. So if you have a `Typey t` value, you know everything there is to know about `t`.

Singleton values are ultimately a hack. `Typey` is not `Type`; it's a value-level stand-in for `Type`'s duplicated type-level copy. In a real dependently-typed system you don't need singleton glue to affix value-level stuff to type-level stuff because the distinction isn't there in the first place.

Our existentially-quantified combinators now look like this. `AComb` packs up a `Comb` with a runtime representation of its type. This technique allows us to guarantee that the boxed `Comb` is well-typed; we just can't say statically what that type is.

```
type AComb = Sg Typey Comb
```

---

How do we write `($$)`, which attempts to apply an `AComb` to another `AComb`? We need to pattern-match on their associated `Typey`s in order to learn whether or not it's possible to apply one to the other. In particular, we're going to need a way to know whether two types are equal.

Here comes *propositional equality*, a GADT proof that two type-level things are equal. You can only give a value of `Refl` if you can explain to GHC that `a` and `b` are in fact the same. Conversely, if you pattern-match on `Refl` then GHC will add `a ~ b` to the typing context.

```
data a :~: b where
    Refl :: a :~: a
withEq :: a :~: b -> (a ~ b => r) -> r
withEq Refl x = x
```

Here's a helper function to lift a pair of equalities through the `:->` constructor.

```
arrEq :: (a :~: c) -> (b :~: d) -> (a :-> b) :~: (c :-> d)
arrEq Refl Refl = Refl
```

As promised, we can write down a function to check whether two `Type`s are equal. We proceed by pattern-matching on their associated singleton `Typey`s, failing if we find the types to be incompatible. If the equality test succeeds, the spoils are a proof that the types are equal.

```
tyEq :: Typey t -> Typey u -> Maybe (t :~: u)
tyEq Unity Unity = Just Refl
tyEq (Arry a b) (Arry c d) = liftA2 arrEq (tyEq a c) (tyEq b d)
tyEq _ _ = Nothing

withTyEq :: Typey t -> Typey u -> (t ~ u => a) -> Maybe a
withTyEq t u x = fmap (\p -> withEq p x) (tyEq t u)
```

Finally, we can write `$$`. The typing rule goes like this:

```
f : a -> b    y : a
------------------- App
      f y : b
```

That is, if the left-hand term of `$$` is a function type, and the type of the right-hand term matches the function's domain, we can type the application. So the implementation of this rule has to test (using `withTyEq`) whether the relevant types match in order to return the resulting term.

```
($$) :: AComb -> AComb -> Maybe AComb
Sg (Arry a b) x $$ Sg t y = withTyEq a t $ Sg b (x :$ y)
_ $$ _ = Nothing
```

---

Generating `Typey` terms corresponds to the act of type-checking. In other words, a function `parse :: String -> AComb` has to do both parsing *and* type-checking. In real compilers, these two phases are separated.

So I'd advise parsing the user input into an *untyped* syntax tree, which admits ill-formed terms, and then generating typing information separately.

```
data Expr = S | K | Expr :$ Expr
parse :: String -> Parser Expr
typeCheck :: Expr -> Maybe AComb
```

A fun exercise (in more-dependently-typed languages) is to modify `typeCheck` to return a more detailed explanation of why type-checking failed, like this bit of pseudo-Agda:

```
data Void : Set where
Not : Set -> Set
Not a = a -> Void

data TypeError : Expr -> Set where
    notArr : Not (IsFunction f) -> TypeError (f :$ x)
    mismatch : Not (domain f :~: type x) -> TypeError (f :$ x)
    inFunc : TypeError f -> TypeError (f :$ x)
    inArg : TypeError x -> TypeError (f :$ x)

typeCheck : (e : Expr) -> Either (TypeError e) AComb
```

You can also make `typeCheck` more precise by giving assurance that it doesn't change the term you give it (another exercise).

For further reading, see [*The View from the Left*](http://strictlypositive.org/vfl.pdf), which features a verified type-checker for the lambda calculus.

Comment: There is a problem with your encoding: `Typey` is monomorphic. I.e. you can't apply `aid :: AComb` to itself. For this to work you'd need to add explicit type variables and change `tyEq` to `tyUnify`.

Comment: Yes, that's a shortcoming of simply-typed systems in general. I glossed over it in the answer because it makes the code significantly more complicated, to the point that (I think) the costs outweigh the benefits of type-indexed terms altogether.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of explanation I'm looking for. Shame it's more complicated with polymorphic types but this helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Not a proper answer, but might be helpful.

Parametricity doesn't allow control flow to depend on types, so you need some first-order representation of types. Haskell has [Typeable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html):

```
deriving instance Typeable Comb

data CombBox = forall a. Typeable a => CombBox { unCombBox :: Comb a }
```

Using it we can define

```
castApply1 :: (Typeable a, Typeable b, Typeable ab) => Comb ab -> Comb a -> Maybe (Comb b)
castApply1 f x = (:$ x) <$> cast f
```

However

```
($$) :: CombBox -> CombBox -> Maybe CombBox
CombBox f $$ CombBox x = CombBox <$> castApply f x
```

throws

```
Could not deduce (Typeable a0) arising from a use of `CombBox' …
    from the context (Typeable a)
    or from (Typeable a1)
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
```

The problem is that `b` is specified in the return type of `castApply1`, but if we immediately apply `CombBox` to `castApply f x`, then `b` doesn't get specified and hence remains ambiguous.

We can specify `b` by providing `Proxy b` as an argument:

```
castApply2 :: (Typeable a, Typeable b, Typeable ab) => Proxy b -> Comb ab -> Comb a -> Maybe (Comb b)
castApply2 p = castApply1
```

Which allows to wrap the result in `CombBox`:

```
castApply3 :: (Typeable a, Typeable b, Typeable ab) => Proxy b -> Comb ab -> Comb a -> Maybe CombBox
castApply3 p f x = CombBox <$> castApply2 p f x
```

We can finally define something that doesn't mention that annoying `b`:

```
data SomeTypeable = forall a. Typeable a => SomeTypeable (Proxy a)

castApply4 :: (Typeable a, Typeable ab) => SomeTypeable -> Comb ab -> Comb a -> Maybe CombBox
castApply4 (SomeTypeable p) = castApply3 p
```

Now having

```
typeRepToSomeTypeable :: TypeRep -> SomeTypeable
```

We can define

```
castApply :: (Typeable a, Typeable ab) => TypeRep -> Comb ab -> Comb a -> Maybe CombBox
castApply t = castApply4 (typeRepToSomeTypeable t)

($$) :: CombBox -> CombBox -> Maybe CombBox
CombBox f $$ CombBox x = funResultTy (typeRep f) (typeRep x) >>= \t -> castApply t f x
```

`funResultTy` is a function in `Data.Typeable` that returns the codomain of a first argument if its domain matches the second argument.

But how to define `typeRepToSomeTypeable`? It doesn't seem it was implemented somewhere. At least I haven't found it neither in `Data.Typeable` nor in [Singletons](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons).

Comment: You'll have to `unsafeCoerce` the `typeRep` into a `Typeable` dictionary, like [the `reflection` library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection-2.1.2/docs/src/Data-Reflection.html#reify) does. This situation should improve in an upcoming version of GHC, where `TypeRep` will be indexed by the type it represents (that is: `class Typeable a where typeRep :: TypeRep a`). Then you'd be able to put the `TypeRep` inside `CombBox` directly, rather than working implicitly with `Typeable` dictionaries: `data CombBox = forall a. CombBox (TypeRep a) (Comb a)`.

Comment: @Benjamin Hodgson, "You'll have to `unsafeCoerce` the `typeRep` into a `Typeable` dictionary" — I don't think you can do that. For this you need to know the target dictionary to remove ambiguity, but there is just no such information. Indexed `TypeRep` will solve the problem of course.